# Draw/Remove geometrical shapes on render target using DirectX 11

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d11

I am trying to draw/remove geometrical shapes on render target which displays a image.

During each frame render, a new image is rendered to the render target by updating the resource via texture mapping which works perfectly as expected.

Now, I'm trying to draw a new geometrical shape filled with a solid color on top of the render target, which is only done during the rendering of every 10th frame.

However currently stuck as to how i should approach this.

I'm using DirectX 11 on windows 7 PC with C# (slimDx or sharpDx for DirectX).

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Code:
During rendring loop i added the code below to draw the overlay which is a triangle in my case.

```
       var device = this.Device;
        var context = device.ImmediateContext;
        var effectsFileResource = Properties.Resources.ShapeEffect;
        ShaderBytecode shaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.Compile(effectsFileResource, "fx_5_0", ShaderFlags.EnableStrictness | ShaderFlags.Debug, EffectFlags.None);

        var effect = new Effect(device, shaderByteCode);

        // create triangle vertex data, making sure to rewind the stream afterward
        var verticesTriangle = new DataStream(VertexPositionColor.SizeInBytes * 3, true, true);
        verticesTriangle.Write(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f), new Color4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
        verticesTriangle.Write(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), new Color4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
        verticesTriangle.Write(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), new Color4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)));

        verticesTriangle.Position = 0;

        // create the triangle vertex layout and buffer
        var layoutColor = new InputLayout(device, effect.GetTechniqueByName("Color").GetPassByIndex(0).Description.Signature, VertexPositionColor.inputElements);
        var vertexBufferColor = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(device, verticesTriangle, (int)verticesTriangle.Length, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
        verticesTriangle.Close();

        var srv = new ShaderResourceView(device, this.RenderTarget);
        effect.GetVariableByName("g_Overlay").AsShaderResource().SetResource(srv);

        // Think of the shared textureD3D10 as an overlay.
        // The overlay needs to show the 2d content but let the underlying triangle (or whatever)
        // show thru, which is accomplished by blending.
        var bsd = new BlendStateDescription();
        bsd.RenderTarget[0].IsBlendEnabled = true;
        bsd.RenderTarget[0].SourceBlend = BlendOption.SourceColor;
        bsd.RenderTarget[0].DestinationBlend = BlendOption.BlendFactor;
        bsd.RenderTarget[0].BlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;
        bsd.RenderTarget[0].SourceAlphaBlend = BlendOption.One;
        bsd.RenderTarget[0].DestinationAlphaBlend = BlendOption.Zero;
        bsd.RenderTarget[0].AlphaBlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;
        bsd.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = ColorWriteMaskFlags.All;

        var blendStateTransparent = new BlendState(device, bsd);

        context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = layoutColor;
        context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip;
        context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(vertexBufferColor, VertexPositionColor.SizeInBytes, 0));
        context.OutputMerger.BlendState = blendStateTransparent;

        var currentTechnique = effect.GetTechniqueByName("Color");
        for (var pass = 0; pass < currentTechnique.Description.PassCount; ++pass)
        {
            using (var effectPass = currentTechnique.GetPassByIndex(pass))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(effectPass.IsValid, "Invalid EffectPass");
                effectPass.Apply(context);
            }
            context.Draw(3, 0);
        };

        srv.Dispose();
```

Also below is the shader file for the effect:

```
Texture2D g_Overlay;

SamplerState g_samLinear
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = CLAMP;
    AddressV = CLAMP;
 };

 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // A shader that accepts Position and Color
 // ------------------------------------------------------

struct ColorVS_IN
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
 };

struct ColorPS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
};

ColorPS_IN ColorVS(ColorVS_IN input)
{
    ColorPS_IN output = (ColorPS_IN)0;
    output.pos = input.pos;
    output.col = input.col;
    return output;
  }

 float4 ColorPS(ColorPS_IN input) : SV_Target
 {
    return input.col;
 }

 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // A shader that accepts Position and Texture
 // Used as an overlay
 // ------------------------------------------------------

 struct OverlayVS_IN
 {
     float4 pos : POSITION;
     float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
  };

  struct OverlayPS_IN
  {
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
  };

  OverlayPS_IN OverlayVS(OverlayVS_IN input)
  {
     OverlayPS_IN output = (OverlayPS_IN)0;
     output.pos = input.pos;
     output.tex = input.tex;
     return output;
   }

  float4 OverlayPS(OverlayPS_IN input) : SV_Target
  {
     float4 color = g_Overlay.Sample(g_samLinear, input.tex);
     return color;
  }

 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // Techniques
 // ------------------------------------------------------

 technique11 Color
 {
    pass P0
    {
        SetGeometryShader(0);
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, ColorVS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, ColorPS()));
     }
  }

  technique11 Overlay
  {
    pass P0
    {
        SetGeometryShader(0);
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, OverlayVS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, OverlayPS()));
    }
  }
```

The above code has been taken from : [SharedResources using SharpDX](https://github.com/ernstnaezer/SharpDXSharedResources)

Comment: Use [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and it's [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: Thanks for the info @ChuckWalbourn However i apology for not mentioning in my post that i am using C#.

Yet I have looked at DirectX Tool Kit which doesn't seem to give me any examples where I could draw/remove geometrical shapes on the render target on every frame rendering.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the C# part. For 3D rendering, you clear and redraw the entire scene every frame. You can then draw over this render target with HUD elements, overlays, and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ChuckWalbourn ok I understand the concept  now. however still a bit confused as to how to draw the overlays which will be my shapes (2d for now) as on one frame i could just display my render target without any overlays and after say 100th frame i wish to show the overlays. Could you provide  some pseudo  code or direct me towards any resources as such. Thanks

Comment: You have to draw the overlay every frame on top of the 3D render target every frame.

Comment: Thanks for the concept @ChuckWalbourn I managed to find a example using SharpDX which does exactly i am trying to do.

I have also added the code above which i have used.

Thanks